# how to parse json in java?

Tags: java, json

I'm new learner of java. can anyone assist me how to parse the following json . I want to get data id from the below code :

```
{"room": {"id": "3","temp": "29"}}
```

Comment: Please try google before posting such a basic question, you will definitely find your annswer faster that way.

Comment: i dnt get proper wayout aftr searching @Keppil

Answer (score 0):

I've used [GSON](http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/) to good effect.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [JSON in Java](http://json.org/java/). It can help you convert JSON strings to java objects and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I've used GSON http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/ and I believe it's the best,

First you create a class to hold your JSON structure

```
Class Room {
    int id;
    int temp;
}
```

And then you parse your string into a json like this

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Room room = gson.fromJson(jsonString, Room.class);
```